# Does the IDbSet Interface exist in .net4

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, repository-pattern

According to MS here it does not:

[.net 5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679233%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

This is to avoid the following:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IQueryable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    T GetById(int id);
}
```

... when implementing the repository and UoW patterns. I remember reading somewhere that you could use IDbSet instead of defining a sample IRepository interface as defined above but I cannot seem to find the msdn page for it and a lot of authors on the web follow the above approach. Even when using EF 4.3 : \

Can you someone shed some light on this please? Or is there an equivalent interface devs should be using in .net 4.0 with E.F ?

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking here. By _.net 4.0_ do you mean EF 4.0? EF 4.3 is also run on .net4

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, the question is about asking if IDbSet is exclusive to .net 5.0 or not. MS on the website give the impression that it is but I have figured out it is available .net4 projects. Regardless of which EF version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `IDbSet` is part of `EntityFramework.dll`, even in the version for .NET 4.0. Documentation for `EntityFramework.dll` (it's not part of the .NET Framework itself) before 5.0 does not appear to be available at MSDN, which is why you have trouble finding it.

Comment: Ty, I just noticed this myself. Thanks for the swift reply.